# c# - Call the good overloaded method from a function with an unkown parameter type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, struct, reference

I am trying to call the good overloaded method from a function with an unkown parameter type. But I always got a conversion error.
How Could I do this ?

Ps I am Trying to not use a if to check the Type.

I Have Try To Change my function to be generic but I got a conversion error.

```
"Impossible to convert ref T in ref MYPROGRAM.MYCLASS.Struct1"
```

My Program:

```
public struct Struct1
{...}

public struct Struct2
{...}

public void EditStruct(ref Struct1 StrucToEdit)
{...}

public void EditStruct(ref Struct2 StrucToEdit)
{...}

public void MyFunction<T>(ref T UnknownStruct)
{
    EditStruct(ref UnknownStruct)
}
```

Thx a lot.

Comment: Do any of the structs have a common interface (or one that can be factored out)? Is there a common set of data being edited in these methods (e.g. Name, etc)?

Comment: @ericrtodd Even if there were an interface, it being a `ref` parameter would prevent you from being able to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using reflection. In this case the reflection results can be very good cached, the performance hit should not be that bad.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            var x = new Struct1() { A = 0, B = -10 };
            var y = new Struct2() { C = 0, D = -10 };

            MyFunction(ref x);
            MyFunction(ref y);
    }


    public static void EditStruct(ref Struct1 structToEdit)
    {
        structToEdit = new Struct1() { A = 10, B = 20 };
    }

    public static void EditStruct(ref Struct2 structToEdit)
    {
        structToEdit = new Struct2() { C = 30, D = 40 };
    }

    private delegate void EditDelegate<T>(ref T obj);

    public static void MyFunction<T>(ref T unknownStruct)
    {
        Delegate d;
        if (!_dict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out d))
        {

            d = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
                .Single(x => x.Name == "EditStruct" && x.GetParameters().SingleOrDefault(y => y.ParameterType.Equals(typeof(T).MakeByRefType())) != null)
                .CreateDelegate(typeof(EditDelegate<T>));
            _dict.Add(typeof(T), d);
        }

        (d as EditDelegate<T>)(ref unknownStruct);
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _dict = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>(new TypeComparer());

    class TypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Type>
    {
        public bool Equals(Type x, Type y) => x.Equals(y);

        public int GetHashCode(Type obj) => obj.GetHashCode();
    }

}

public struct Struct1
{
    public int A;
    public int B;
}

public struct Struct2
{
    public int C;
    public int D;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it. Look to be exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Very small OO example that might help - in this example the code to perform the editing is encapsulated away using the `IStructEditor` interface:

```
public static class StructEditor
{
    public static void Edit<TStruct, TEditor>(ref TStruct s)
        where TEditor : IStructEditor<TStruct>, new()
    {
        new TEditor()
            .EditStuct(ref s);
    }
}

public interface IStructEditor<T>
{
    void EditStuct(ref T s);
}

struct CostStruct
{
    public int Cost;
}

class SetCost
    : IStructEditor<CostStruct>
{
    public void EditStuct(ref CostStruct s)
    {
        s.Cost = 123;
    }
}
```

So you can use this as follows:

```
CostStruct s = new CostStruct();
StructEditor.Edit<CostStruct, SetCost>(ref s);
```

Meaning you can quickly define new behaviors by implementing `IStructEditor`!

Answer (score 0):

I dont' even understand what are you doing, but it seams unnecessary to do any casting on a generic method, the type is already known!

Just call `EditStruct(ref UnknownStructCasted)`, deleting first line.

Parameter is of type T, not `dynamic`. It will be only if you call your method

```
EditStruct(new dynamic{
   //some data
  });
```

Aren't you?

Working sample:

```
internal class Program
    {
        public enum WhatToDo
        {
            Something,
            SomethingElse
        }

        public static void MyMethod(WhatToDo what)
        {
            switch (what)
            {
                case WhatToDo.Something:
                    Struct1 param1 = new Struct1();
                    MygenericMethod(param1);
                    break;
                case WhatToDo.SomethingElse:
                    Struct2 param2 = new Struct2();
                    MygenericMethod(param2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void MygenericMethod<T>(T someParam) where T : struct
        {
        }

        public struct Struct1
        {
        }

        public struct Struct2
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: That wont compile. A `T` can not be used in `Editstruct`

Comment: @Oscar I have updated my question but InBetween Is right i got a conversion error ?

Comment: @InBetween You're right, that's why I said first that I don't understand what's the point with it. It should be public void EditStruct(T someParam)
{...}

Comment: @InBetween how could i fix this?

Comment: @MrRubix I have tested the new code, it should compile now

Comment: @Oscar the use of a enum is imo not i clean solution.

Comment: @Rabban IMHO is better than switching over a type, at least it's making  clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @Oscar This work for my generic method but i need to call my overloaded method in my generic method. Can you add the overloaded method to your answer, When i try it  i always got a conversion error between ref T and ref Struct

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a common interface for your structs, consider something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IStruct s1 = new Struct1();
        IStruct s2 = new Struct2();

        EditStruct(ref s1);
        EditStruct(ref s2);
    }

    static void EditStruct(ref IStruct target)
    {
        target.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}

public interface IStruct
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public struct Struct1 : IStruct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public struct Struct2: IStruct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This forces the caller to box the struct before passing it in.  If they didn't already have a boxed struct, then they don't get `ref` semantics.